# Can't SVN checkout repository; Server doesn't receive request

Tags: svn, timeout, vps, centos6

I have a VPS. From this VPS, I'm trying to checkout a repository at `svn://svn.server.dom/repos`. Some time after, I receive a timeout message.

If I run `ping svn.server.dom`, it works fine.

Here's the thing though: the server *is not even receiving* the svn request. I talked to the network admin, and the server receives the ping command with no issues (I also receive the server response), but the svn request doesn't even show up in the log. So I would guess that my VPS can't reach the server, but then the ping shouldn't work either!

Trying to checkout from other machines works fine. I'm running CentOS 6 and SVN 1.8.1 on the VPS.

What can possibly be happening?

Apparently svn is blocked somewhere(?) for security concerns. See the question at [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/653327/cant-checkout-svn-repository-server-doesnt-receive-request) for details.

Comment: While this may be on-topic here at StackOverflow, you'll likely get a better response on [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/) as your question seems to be concerned primarily with server configuration/troubleshooting.

Comment: I went there first, but their "specific guidelines" of not home/development environment and "professional capacity" drove me off a bit. I'll try there if I can't find a answer here.

Answer (score 1):

By default `svn://` means using port 3690, which can (**must** really) be blocked on any border between hops. You can test connectivity, using (from VPS side) `telnet svn.server.dom 3690`